# Site is not executing PHP code when Migrated from Apache to Nginx server

Tags: php, apache, nginx, fastcgi

Recently I migrated the site from the Apache server to the Nginx server, On this Nginx server there is already another PHP site is hosted, but only the PHP code of this migrated site is not executing.

Below is a conf file for this site. When I try to run the site on the browser only Html code is displaying and PHP code is not executing.

```
server {
       listen 80;
       server_name xyzorg.in;             
       return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    server_name xyzorg.in; 

    ssl     on;
    ssl_certificate      /etc/pki/tls/certs/xyzorg_in.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/pki/tls/certs/xyzorg_in.key;

    ssl_session_timeout  5m;
    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping

    root /usr/local/www/site;
    index index.html index.php report.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    location / {
       try_files $uri $uri?$args $uri/ /index.php?$uri&$args /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;        
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off;}
    location = /robots.txt { log_not_found off; access_log off;}
    location ~ /.well-known { allow all; }
}
```

In the apache server, there was a .htaccess file with the below code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xyzorg.in [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.xyzorg.in/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} index\.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: nginx does not have .htaccess support.

Comment: https://www.nginx.com/blog/converting-apache-to-nginx-rewrite-rules/

Comment: Try replacing `fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;` with `fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;` - or something similar depending where is PHP socket located in your system and which version is installled. Use `ls -l /var/run/php/` or `ls -l /var/run/` to determine.